# form missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have used same code for forms in previous apps but this time it doesnt seem to work, migrations have been done and i have been at this for a day and cant find a good solution of why this form isnt working.

```
def gst_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = gst_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/")

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Details Invalid")  


    else:
        form = gst_form()
        
    context= {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'main/form.html', context)
```

Comment: you did name your view the same as the form. So instead of constructing a new form, you will make a recursive call.

Comment: Please give your form class a *different* name. Normally this is in `PerlCase` (not `snake_case`).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have given *both* your view and your form `gst_form` as name. This thus means that when you call `gst_form` in your view, you make a recursive call to the view function, you thus do *not* construct a form.

An easy way to solve this is to rename your form, for example to `GstForm`:

```
class GstForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # …
```

then there is no longer a name clash:

```
from ….forms import GstForm

# …

def gst_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GstForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = GstForm()
    context= { 'form': form }
    return render(request, 'main/form.html', context)
```

Furthermore this is also compliant with the [PEP-0008 style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names):

> **Class names** should normally use the **`CapWords` convention**.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i have been at this bug for over an hour.